# Why is my website exceeding max questions?

Tags: wordpress

This is my first post, and I apologize for being such a noob.  I have started to develop a website using Wordpress.  It is very basic at this stage.  Only a few pages, some plugins and no additional CSS.  To my knowledge I do not have any visitors yet.  While working in the Dashboard/ admin side, I am often getting redirected to the wp-admin/install.php

After extensive searching and an error that finally popped up, it seems to be an issue with max questions being exceeded.  I am using a free hosting service.  I have seen quite a bit of suggestions on how to increase the max limit but cannot find any info on what the root cause/ problem is.  What causes this high question demand?  What are "questions"?  Is it a plugin causing my issues?  Do most wp dashboard websites have such high demand on the database?  And is there any detriment to simply increasing the limit, rather than removing the cause which are sending the questions?

Thank you in advance
Gary

I have tried to repair the mysql database
I have checked the prefix in the config file and the url, etc

Comment: Give us the actual error, because it's probably saying *queries*, not "questions". Your issue is probably that you're on free hosting, where resources will be heavily constrained.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  This is the message that displays on the wp-admin/install.php redirect page:           
"WordPress database error: [User '3018141_wpressxxxxxxxxxx' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 12000)]
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('wpsupercache_gc_time', '1561059593', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)"

Answer (score 0):

Your host has limited the number of queries your account can make, likely on an hourly/daily basis.

You can reduce the number of queries by implementing caching in your WordPress install, but fundamentally this is a very, very low limit and that's because you're using free, shared hosting. Both free and shared hosting typically come with *severe* resource limits as they're already unprofitable as-is.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful answers.  I thought there was something wrong with my site or a plugin, but if 12000 is a very low limit, then I will explore ways to increase it.  What kind of limits are available on paid hosting?

Comment: When I try to open phpMyAdmin, I get the following message: Error
Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "CHARACTER SET" at position 4)
Unexpected token. (near "'utf8mb4'" at position 18)
SQL query: Edit Edit

SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4';

MySQL said: Documentation

#1226 - User '3018141_wpress5ab5fce6' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource (current value: 12000)  How can I fix these errors, please?